# UIImagePickerController takePicture Dismisses Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

I have a custom `UIImagePickerController` that works nicely, only I am facing one issue that I feel should be fairly simple - I just have yet to figure out the solution.

Upon touching my custom added "photo" button, I have it targeted to the build in `takePicture` method of the UIIPC. Here is my code

```
@interface CustomCameraController ()

@end

@implementation CustomCameraController {
    CGFloat width, height;
}

- (instancetype)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        width = self.view.frame.size.width, height = self.view.frame.size.height;
        self.allowsEditing = YES;
        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.showsCameraControls = NO;
        self.toolbarHidden = YES;

        [self buildCameraOverlay];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)buildCameraOverlay {

    UIView *customOverlay = [UIView alloc] ...
    // ... Custom overlay setup done here

    _takePhoto = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, heightBottomBar*.5, heightBottomBar*.5)];
    _takePhoto.center = CGPointMake(bottomBar.frame.size.width/2, bottomBar.frame.size.height/2);
    [_takePhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera button icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_takePhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(takePicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bottomBar addSubview:_takePhoto];

    // ... 

    self.cameraOverlayView = customOverlay;
}
```

This is done in my custom controller `CustomCameraController init` call.

The problem is, upon taking the picture via `takePicture`, the camera shutter goes off, everything works just fine, but the controller dismisses itself. I'm trying to figure out how to stop it from closing immediately after taking the picture, so  I can A)present the taken picture, and B) give the user the option to choose the image or cancel and retake another one (returning to the camera)

If anyone knows why this happens or something that I am missing / doing incorrectly please let me know. I'm sure it's a simple answer - just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide code for your `takePicture` method, as well as delegate methods for `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: ....... delegate problem. I feel silly.

Comment: if you would like, post setting del as an answer and I'll accept it otherwise im going to delete this silly question

Comment: don't worry, this happens to the best of us. I'll post the answer shortly so that people can refer it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason for such a weird behaviour is usually lack of delegate methods (for `UIImagePickerController` in this case) or their wrong implementation.